# Boolean Filter for checkboxes in ng-model Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

item.imposed is either 1, or 0.

In order for a checkbox to mark as checked, the value must be true or false.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.imposed">
```

You cannot use a filter inside of ng-model, how can this be accomplished simply and correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ngChecked`, but you won't get any binding back to your model:

http://jsfiddle.net/fMBQj/

Or you can use `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue`, but you HAVE to use a string (not an int):

http://jsfiddle.net/fMBQj/1/

Or you can use a custom directive... it's pretty lame right now.

Comment: Langdon to the rescue! ngTrueValue works great, and it will work for many other value. Thanks tons

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-value-true to tell angular that your ng-model is a string.

I could only get ng-true-value working if I added the extra quotes like so (as shown in the official Angular docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

```
ng-true-value="'1'"
```